# Field of class has null after initialization in the method of class

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I know that this is not a serious question (and my code is not perfect...), but I wonder why after initialization of the field, which passed as a parameter to the method, the field has a null pointer (null)?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
private ProgressDialog prdialog;

    ProgressDialog prepareDialog(ProgressDialog pr){
        if (pr==null){
            pr=new ProgressDialog(this);
        }
        pr.setTitle(R.string.Download);
        pr.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pr.setCancelable(false);
        pr.setMessage(getString(R.string.Wait_));
        return pr;
    }
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prepareDialog(prdialog).show();
        //do some operations
        prdialog.dismiss();//here my app is crashes because prdialog=null
    }
}
```

Comment: Which field are you referring to ?

Comment: What statement do you think should be setting `prdialog`?

Comment: You're not assigning anything to `prdialog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java only uses pass-by-value for parameters. See [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

This means that the line

```
    prepareDialog(prdialog).show();
```

does **not** update the value of `prdialog` (and although it does produce a result, you're not assigning it to the `prdialog` member either) . Hence, it's null later. What you want to do is probably:

```
ProgressDialog prepareDialog() {
    ProgressDialog pr = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pr.setTitle(R.string.Download);
    pr.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    pr.setCancelable(false);
    pr.setMessage(getString(R.string.Wait_));
    return pr;
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    prdialog = prepareDialog();
    prdialog.show();
    //do some operations
    prdialog.dismiss();
}
```

An alternative solution (in case you want to call `prepareDialog()` multiple times, but reusing the dialog instead of creating a new one), would be:

```
void prepareDialog() {
    if (prDialog == null)
        prDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    prDialog.setTitle(R.string.Download);
    prDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    prDialog.setCancelable(false);
    prDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.Wait_));
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    prepareDialog();

    prdialog.show();
    //do some operations
    prdialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: The solution isn't quite right.  I think he was trying to get `prepareDialog` to create a new `ProgressDialog` only the first time, and your solution creates a new one every time.

Comment: @ajb Since it's called in `onCreate()`, I thought that wasn't necessary. But a fair point, I'll correct the example.

Comment: I always thought that java passes objects by reference, as in C++.

Comment: We don't know for sure that it isn't called somewhere else, also.  In addition, looking at the Android activity lifecycle, it looks as though `onCreate()` could be called more than once on the same object.

Comment: @Vladislav Follow the link at the top of the answer.  This will help explain things.

Comment: @ajb You're completely correct about the first point. But not about the second :) An Activity won't call onCreate() a second time, unless it's destroyed (and at that point it will be a different instance).

Comment: OK, then.  I'm not yet an expert on Android, and the documentation of `onCreate()` isn't clear and I should know better than to trust that diagrams mean what they think they mean.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your call `**prepareDialog(prdialog).show();**` passes the reference of your `**prdialog**` object, but the method returns a fully constructed object that you ignore. As java is only pass by value (the value of reference is being passed here), you need to keep the reference of the returned object.

you have to do something like `prdialog = prepareDialog(prdialog);`. After that, your prdialog object will be fully constructed for your use.